# How to make custom programming language in blockly by react

Tags: reactjs, blockly

By now I know what the format of the generator is, the only question is I don't know where the '**goog**' comes from.

Here is the partial code from my 'generator/arduino.js'

```js
import * as Blockly from 'blockly/core'
// goog.provide('Blockly.Arduino')
// goog.require('Blockly.Generator')

/*
* Arduino generator
* @type {!Blockly.Generator}
* */
Blockly.Arduino = new Blockly.Generator('Arduino')

// ... the rest
```

I don't know where to import **goog** and I can't find 'closure/goog/base.js' in node_modules

When I try to manually add goog in package.json, there goes the error "import the same project repeatedly"

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe this? https://github.com/nbudin/react-blockly

Comment: @Nathaniel Flick This project shows a nice way to implement blockly in react, but still doesn't tell how to generate other programming languages.

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)